# Flutter Will Not Read HintText?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I am currently trying to write a test for a SignUpPage that. The very first thing I do in the test is:

`await tester.enterText(find.text('Enter First Name'), 'Jimmy');`

The 'Enter First Name' text, however, is actually Hint Text Within a Padding Widget:

```
Padding(
              padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 200, vertical: 16),
                child: TextFormField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      hintText: 'Enter First Name'),
                  controller: firstNameController,
                ),
              )
```

I want to be able to enter text upon finding the 'Enter First Name' hintText. How can I do that?

I tried using all of the other find functions within the find class. None of them worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to search a text field by the hint text e.g. once you update the hint text or apply the translation to it, your tests may break. I would recommend using one of the following methods:

1. Assign a key for the `TextFormField` and search by it:

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
    horizontal: 200,
    vertical: 16,
  ),
  child: TextFormField(
    key: const Key('firstNameTextFormField'),
    decoration: const InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      hintText: 'Enter First Name',
      controller: firstNameController,
    ),
  ),
);

// Then in your tests

await tester.enterText(find.byKey('firstNameTextFormField'), 'Jimmy');
```

2. Search your `TextFormField` by type (in case there is one text field provided in the Widget you test:

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
    horizontal: 200,
    vertical: 16,
  ),
  child: TextFormField(
    decoration: const InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      hintText: 'Enter First Name',
      controller: firstNameController,
    ),
  ),
);

// Then in your tests

await tester.enterText(find.byType(TextFormField), 'Jimmy');
```